# get only the max create date from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, get, max

I want to get data from a table, but only select the latest or the max `CreateDate`

here's my query :

```
select Username, Password,Status,FirstLogin,CreateDate,UpdateDate,MasterID,FullName,Address,tm.Email,TempEmail,VerificationCode,PhoneNo,TempPhonoNo,TempPassword,LastSignIn,TempAccount,bod,ktp,Gender,CustType,VIP from UserData t 
    inner join (
        select Email, max(CreateDate) as MaxDate
        from userdata
        group by Email
    ) tm on t.Email = tm.Email and t.CreateDate = tm.MaxDate
```

but unfortunately I just get multiple result for the same email, I just want to get only 1 email that has max create date  :

here's the exact same create date :

```
CreateDate                          FullName        Email   
2012-08-14 16:37:16.900     Mrs a       yyyyy@yyy.com   
2012-08-14 16:37:16.900     mrs a       yyyy@yyyy.com
```

and here's with diffrent create date :

```
2012-11-24 20:34:44.930 0   zzzzz       zzzzz@zzz.com
2012-11-16 08:13:45.217 0   zzzz    zzzz@zzzz.com
```

but I only want to have result like this :

```
 CreateDate                         FullName        Email   
    2012-08-14 16:37:16.900     Mrs a       yyyyy@yyy.com
2012-11-24 20:34:44.930 0   zzzzz       zzzzz@zzz.com
```

Comment: In both your examples, you are only getting one result for each email (there are different numbers of ys and zs in the email) -- is that a mistake?

Comment: no, i mean I give an sample, the first 1 I just want to get only one email result, the second one I just want to get te only result from 24/11/2012 but my query show multiple result like that

Comment: Try select distinct the data for the inner joint part. If not use select TOP 1 to return the first row only? However base on your example I'm seeing 2 different emails instead. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Sky I tried distinct but give the same result

Comment: I update the questions to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't getting enough uniqueness to use GROUP BY or DISTINCT, you could use ROW_NUMBER. It's not the fastest function, but it will give you uniqueness. e.g.

```
SELECT
     I.CreateDate
    ,I.FullName
    ,I.Email
FROM (
    SELECT
         T.CreateDate
        ,T.FullName
        ,T.Email
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                            PARTITION BY T.Email 
                            ORDER BY T.FullName
                           ) SEQ
    FROM UserData t
        INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT 
                        Email
                        ,MAX(CreateDate) AS MaxDate
                    FROM userdata
                    GROUP BY Email
                    ) TM
            ON T.Email = TM.Email
                AND T.CreateDate = TM.MaxDate
    ) I
WHERE I.SEQ = 1
```

Comment: wow, works like a charm give one latest create date result of every data

Comment: Glad I could help. I use row_number all the time for ordering sequenced events

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a pretty easy way to get what you want:

```
select Username, Password, Status, FirstLogin, CreateDate, UpdateDate, MasterID, FullName,  
       Address, Email, TempEmail, VerificationCode, PhoneNo, TempPhonoNo, TempPassword,    
       LastSignIn, TempAccount, bod, ktp, Gender, CustType, VIP
from (select ud.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by CreateDate desc) as seqnum
      from UserData ud
     ) ud
where seqnum = 1;
```

You only need to use the window function `row_number()` and have no need for other joins or aggregations.